# How to send out an Email notification in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

How to send out an Email notification in selenium webdriver using java, whenever some scenario is failed/passed in between ??

Comment: thanks down voter.. helping is not good always..just deleted answer as down voted..

Comment: I don't think sending out mail for each testcase is an good idea, try summarising all test in some kind of report (testNG, HTML, simple text, extentReport) and send it cumulatively. But bellow is code how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will allow you to send mail using JAVA. Create one function and call it after scenario of Pass/Fail in selenium webdriver code.

```
final String username = "YourEmail";
final String password = "YourPassword";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.example.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
props.put("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
}
});

try {

Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("YourEmail"));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
    InternetAddress.parse("Emailid to which you want to send Report"));
message.setSubject("Email Subject");



BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();  
messageBodyPart1.setText("Body text);  

//4) create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object to this object      
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();  

String filename = "File path if you want to attach in mail";//change accordingly  
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);  
messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));  
messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);  


//5) create Multipart object and add MimeBodyPart objects to this object      
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);  
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);  

//6) set the multiplart object to the message object  
message.setContent(multipart );  
Transport.send(message);

System.out.println("Mail Sent Successfully");

 } catch (MessagingException e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

**Note :** Please change Host, Email details and port as per your Email system configuration.

Comment: Can u please explain me clearly?? I am expecting notification mail whenever test case pass/fail.. For example : Consider I am automating facebook login page. what i am expecting is, click on the login button should trigger email notification saying that successful login/ login failed.. I am expecting Email notification in between execution.

Comment: For test case Pass/Fail , you can use assertion , and after that call this mail function to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a method in Utility class file and call it from condition where test case fails.

```
public static void sendEmail(string message, string testCaseName)
{
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add("your-to-email-address-goes-here");
mail.From = new MailAddress("your-from-email-address-goes-here ");
mail.Subject = "your-mail-subject-goes-here";
mail.Body = "Test Case Name: " + testCaseName;
mail.Body += Environment.NewLine;
mail.Body += message;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "localhost";
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

You can call this method in your test case, when it should fail. User will be notified via email.

**use proper SMTP configuration

Comment: Can u please explain me clearly?? i am expecting notification mail whenever test case pass..

Comment: You can call above method when your testcase has executed successfully  by passing the parameters.

Comment: Can u please explain me clearly?? I am expecting notification mail whenever test case pass/fail.. For example : Consider I am automating facebook login page. what i am expecting is, click on the login button should trigger email notification saying that successful login/ login failed.. I am expecting Email notification in between execution.

Comment: In case if you want to mark test case as pass or fail then you can use assertion and if in between of your code if you want to send email depending upon login success or such then you can call this method. For ex: when you have verified that login has been success then you can call this method with parameter values. You can change the signatures of the method as required. You just have to place a method call on your success or failure condition as required.

Comment: Okay Understood.  Need to add any external jar files??

Comment: Use "import javax.mail.*;" .

Comment: Getting error in the following lines.                                                        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("your-from-email-address-goes-here ");   mail.Body += Environment.NewLine;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

Comment: Paste the error and try to search for a resolution. Tweak in the code as required.

Comment: MailMessage cannot be resolved to a type. What imports did you use @Abhinav

Comment: I dont have access to code now to check but I guess it was - import javax.mail.*;

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample for sending out emails via javax.mail:

pom dependancy:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>
```

**1. STEP (model MailMessage) you need model class of mail message:**

```
    public class MailMessage {
    private String from;
    private List<String> to;
    private List<String> cc;
    private List<String> bcc;
    private String subject;
    private Date sendDate;
    private String flags;
    private String content;
    private List<File> attachments;

    public MailMessage() {
    }


    public MailMessage(String from, String to, String subject, String content) 
        List<String> listTo = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listCC = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listBCC = new ArrayList<>();
        listTo.add(to);
        new MailMessage(from, listTo, listCC, listBCC, subject, content);
    }

    public MailMessage(String from, String to, String cc, String subject, String content) {
        List<String> listTo = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listCC = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listBCC = new ArrayList<>();
        listTo.add(to);
        listCC.add(cc);
        new MailMessage(from, listTo, listCC, listBCC, subject, content);

    }

    public MailMessage(String from, List<String> to, List<String> cc, List<String> bcc, String subject, String content) {
        setFrom(from);
        setTo(to);
        setCc(cc);
        setBcc(bcc);
        setSubject(subject);
        setContent(content);
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public List<String> getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(List<String> to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public List<String> getCc() {
        return cc;
    }

    public void setCc(List<String> cc) {
        this.cc = cc;
    }

    public List<String> getBcc() {
        return bcc;
    }

    public void setBcc(List<String> bcc) {
        this.bcc = bcc;
    }


    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public Date getSendDate() {
        return sendDate;
    }

    public void setSendDate(Date sendDate) {
        this.sendDate = sendDate;
    }

    public String getFlags() {
        return flags;
    }

    public void setFlags(String flags) {
        this.flags = flags;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String fieldMessage) {
        this.content = fieldMessage;
    }

    public List<File> getAttachments() {
        return attachments;
    }

    public void setAttachments(List<File> attachments) {
        this.attachments = attachments;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("-------------------------------------\n");
        sb.append("FROM: " + getFrom() + "\n");
        sb.append("TO: " + getTo() + "\n");
        sb.append("Subject: " + getSubject() + "\n");
        sb.append("Send Date: " + getSendDate() + "\n");
        sb.append("Flags: " + getFlags() + "\n");
        sb.append("Messages: " + getContent() + "\n");
        sb.append("-------------------------------------\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**2. STEP (create message, populate model)**

```
protected MailMessage createMessage(String to, String subject, String content) {
    List<String> listTo = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> listCC = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> listBCC = new ArrayList<>();
    listTo.add(to);
    return createMessage(listTo, listCC, listBCC, subject, content);
}

protected MailMessage createMessage(List<String> to, List<String> cc, List<String> bcc, String subject, String content) {
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.setFrom(getUsername());
    mailMessage.setTo(to);
    mailMessage.setCc(cc);
    mailMessage.setBcc(bcc);
    mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
    mailMessage.setContent(content);
    return mailMessage;
}
```

**3. STEP method for sending message via model (MailMessage):**

```
public boolean sendMessage(MailMessage mailMessage) {

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(getSession());

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailMessage.getFrom()));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        for (String fieldTo : mailMessage.getTo()) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(fieldTo));
        }

        for (String fieldCc : mailMessage.getCc()) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(fieldCc));
        }

        for (String fieldBcc : mailMessage.getBcc()) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(fieldBcc));
        }

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject(mailMessage.getSubject());

        // Now set the actual message
        message.setText(mailMessage.getContent());


        // creates message part
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(mailMessage.getContent(), "text/html");

        // creates multi-part
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // adds attachments
        if (mailMessage.getAttachments() != null && mailMessage.getAttachments().size() > 0) {
            for (File filePath : mailMessage.getAttachments()) {
                MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                try {
                    attachPart.attachFile(filePath.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
            }
        }

        // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
        message.setContent(multipart);


        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        return true;

    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this would help,